# ¿Como asignar un puntero char a una celda de DataGridView?

Tags: c++, punteros, datagridview, visual, studio

Cuando intento asignar un char* yytext a una celda de datagridview me sale este error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uykz.png
Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionarlo?
ERROR: void System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCell::Value::set(System::Object ^)': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'char *' a 'System::Object ^'

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: Este error me sale void System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCell::Value::set(System::Object ^)': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'char *' a 'System::Object ^'

Comment: el error es en donde asigno el yytext

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion en la pregunta...